# keystore.jks to be used in Java application

Tags: certificate, java-7, keystore

I have a `java application`, which connects to some web service. When I try to call web service's function(s), I get an exception .

Although if I call the same web service function(s) from my other `web application`, which is deployed on `tomcat 7` server , it works fine.

Only difference is that I have `keystore.jks` file in Tomcat's home folder.

How can I make my java application use the `keystore.jks` file, since my guess is that it's the reason my application fails to work ?

Here is the stack trace of an exception :

```
2013-10-11 15:24:14.0685 DEBUG main org.apache.axis.enterprise – Mapping Exception to AxisFault
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.tieto.issuing.ws.Issuing.IssuingSoapBindingStub.addCardToStop(IssuingSoapBindingStub.java:2398)
    at ge.ufc.cscupdator.utils.IssuingWsOperationManager.addCardToStopList(IssuingWsOperationManager.java:74)
    at ge.ufc.cscupdator.CardStopCauseUpdator.main(CardStopCauseUpdator.java:51)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exported `certificate` from web browser and then imported it in `cacert` in `"PATH_TO_JAVA"\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\security` with `keytool`

Answer (score 1):

This error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

indicates that the client received the SSL certificate chain from the server but was not able to verify this chain using the trust anchor (aka root CA) certificates. The default trust anchor list is stored in the `lib/security/cacerts` keystore file in the Java home directory.

To specify another trust store for the SSL trust anchor (in that case it is called a trust store) you have to pass this option to the client:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/trsutstore
```

This trust store should contain the Root CA certificate of the server SSL certificate chain. Actually `keystore.jks` *may* contain this certifcate but it also *may not*. I suggest you use the `keytool` tool with the `-list` command to verify if the root CA certificate is present.